# Django Postgres django.db.utils.ProgrammingError

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I know similar questions have been asked many times, but none of those solutions have worked.

Recently I have been trying to connect to an AWS RDS database. However, now whenever I try to run a server through manage.py migrate my database I always get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "employee_employeeprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."employee_employeeprofile"."additional_info" FROM "employee_...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/debug_toolbar/apps.py", line 15, in ready
    dt_settings.patch_all()
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 228, in patch_all
    patch_root_urlconf()
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 216, in patch_root_urlconf
    reverse('djdt:render_panel')
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 568, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 360, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 293, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/mobility/mobility/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mobility.apps.iam import urls as iam_urls
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/mobility/mobility/apps/iam/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/mobility/mobility/apps/iam/views.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..employee.views import employee_profile
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/mobility/mobility/apps/employee/views.py", line 261, in <module>
    class EmployeeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/mobility/mobility/apps/employee/views.py", line 267, in EmployeeFilter
    functional_area_name = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(name ="functional_area_name", choices = get_func_names())
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/mobility/mobility/apps/employee/views.py", line 226, in get_func_names
    for e in EmployeeProfile.objects.all():
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/somil/Documents/Twine/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "employee_employeeprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."employee_employeeprofile"."additional_info" FROM "employee_...
```

I have tried deleting all migrations and trying to make them again but this error persists. I also get this error on any new local databases I create. Any suggestions? I feel like I get this error often and the only way I can easily fix it is to delete the DB and create it again, but this time that doesn't even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling your `get_func_names()` function, which queries the EmployeeProfile model, at class level in your EmployeeFilter class. This means it is called at import time. Since the views are imported on startup, your migrations have not yet had a chance to run.

You should not call any code that accesses the database at import time.

Comment: Wow pretty simple mistake -- should have dug into the error message more. I will rethink the organization of my code

Comment: Exact issue: had a function that made a db query within class variables